# How to simply enable HAL+JSON object mapping with Spring Restemplate

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to simply enable this sort of functionality in my client in response to a HAL+JSON request. If I have the specific resource I can get the properties to bind but really would like the hrefs in an easy to use format so I can lazy fetch them.

Organization[] orgs = restTemplate.getForObject("http://myservice/organizations",Organizations[].class);

or

Organization org = restTemplate.getForObject("http://myservice/organizations/1",Organization.class);

Given the following HAL and entities:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "af:organizations": [
            {
                "name": "First Company",
                "description": "Some company",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/hal/organizations/1"
                    },
                    "af:workers": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/hal/organizations/1/workers",
                        "title": "Cancel an order"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Second Company",
                "description": "Someplace we all used to work",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/hal/organizations/2"
                    },
                    "af:workers": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/hal/organizations/2/workers",
                        "title": "All the little ants on your farm"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/hal/organizations"
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/hal/profile/organizations"
        },
        "curies": [
            {
                "href": "/custom/docs/{rel}.txt",
                "name": "af",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

entity

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Organization {

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @JsonProperty("_links")
    private Map<String, Link> links;

}
```

Configuration (which is my 3rd attempt. It's just my current one)

```
@Configuration
@EnablePluginRegistries(RelProvider.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:ant-farm-client.properties")
public class AntFarmClientConfig {

    @Value("${server.url}")
    private String base;


    private static final boolean EVO_PRESENT =
            ClassUtils.isPresent("org.atteo.evo.inflector.English", null);

    @Autowired
    private PluginRegistry<RelProvider, Class<?>> relProviderRegistry;


    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        return objectMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter = new
                MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        jacksonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.valueOf("application/json")));
        jacksonConverter.setObjectMapper(jacksonObjectMapper());
        return jacksonConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CurieProvider curieProvider() {
        return new DefaultCurieProvider("af", new UriTemplate("http://schema.org/{rel}"));
    }


    @Bean
    MessageSourceAccessor accessor(ApplicationContext context) {
        return new MessageSourceAccessor(context);
    }
    @Bean
    public RestOperations template(ObjectMapper mapper,MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter halConverter ) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        DefaultUriTemplateHandler handler = new DefaultUriTemplateHandler();
        handler.setBaseUrl(base);
        restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(handler);

        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(halConverter);
        return restTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter halConverter(MessageSourceAccessor accessor) {
        CurieProvider curieProvider = curieProvider();

        RelProvider relProvider = new DelegatingRelProvider(relProviderRegistry);
        ObjectMapper halObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        halObjectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

        halObjectMapper.registerModule(new Jackson2HalModule());
        halObjectMapper.setHandlerInstantiator(new
                Jackson2HalModule.HalHandlerInstantiator(relProvider, curieProvider,accessor));

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter halConverter = new  MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        halConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON));
        halConverter.setObjectMapper(halObjectMapper);

        return halConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    RelProvider defaultRelProvider() {
        return EVO_PRESENT ? new EvoInflectorRelProvider() : new DefaultRelProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    RelProvider annotationRelProvider() {
        return new AnnotationRelProvider();
    }
```

Comment: Just to make it clear: you want to have access to the list of links from inside the _Organization_ instance, is that it?

Comment: I have since Made changes to get that. I would love to use Jayway to slim it down. I will update the code with the changes.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to get a `Resources<Resource<Organization>>` out of the RestTemplate. The outer `Resources` would contain the global links and each `Resource` in the content contains the item links then.

I would not create my own ObjectMapper - spring hateoas provides one. It is just important that your RestTemplate has the `HttpMessageConverter` in place that can convert `application/hal+json`.

This article shows an example for doing this https://dzone.com/articles/spring-resttemplate-linked

Currently I cannot try this myself so I can just provide you with these untested thoughts.

Comment: Your comments are on the money. I am going down this road now and trying to figure out how to use the API's best. I have also been digesting this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/  I am, however, trying to figure out how to get it to work when I enable curying for documentation.

Comment: When I extend "ResourceSupport", with already has "links" I actually don't get them marshalled.

Comment: As I said - I was just guessing - but if you have a reproduction case on github I would be happy to try the one thing or the other